# Validate in a separate class, or as method of writer class?

Tags: php, oop, validation

Should input validation be done with a separate class, rather than in a DB write class? Or should it be a method of the writing class?

Eg. (shorthand version)

```
class DBWrite {

   public function add($input) {
       $data = new Validator($input);
       if($data->isValid() == true) {
           // write to DB
       }
   }

}
```

or would it be better to have the validation as part of the DBWrite class? Or would it be in too much of violation in terms with separation of concerns (or something else)?

```
class DBWrite {

   public function add($input) {
       if($this->inputIsValid() == true) {
           // write to DB
       }
   }

   private function inputIsValid() {
       // Check that input is valid and return true if it is
   }
}
```

Any other thoughts will also be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Validator can be used in other classes than DBWrite, or if later you may want to swap out validators later, I'd go the route of separate Validator class and subclasses.  You might also want to add a method to set/get your validator class in your DBWrite so you can swap out different validators at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need no validation at that level. Either the object can be stored or it is in a state that the database layer rejects it - you will then see a database exception.

The database itself normally takes care that the data is in proper order and valid.

But sure you can double the work and validate each time an object is being passed from one layer to another - and ensure you do it on both layers: On the output side of the first layer and on the input side of the second layer.

But normally only input validation and database validation is needed.

Input validation means, that you validate the objects when they come from within your storage layer, not when you put them into it.

Also input validation naturally means that you validate the objects when they come from other sources of input. But here again, not when stored.